# PHPExcel : Create multiple sheets from different html files

Tags: php, html, google-sheets, phpexcel

We are using PHP Excel library to create excel file with multiple sheets. 
    We need to load multiple html page contents in multiple sheets.
    We strong text have successfully implemented 1 sheet with dynamic data from HTML.
    When I add second sheets it returns excel with latest sheet added only.

```
Below is code

        <?php 
                require_once './PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
                require_once './PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
                   // Create new PHPExcel object
                    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
                    //Create a first sheet, representing sales data
                    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');


                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
                    //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'aaaaaaa');
                    $objPHPExcel= $objReader->load('./report_html/report1.html');
                    // Rename sheet
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Sheet1 ');

                    //----------------------------------------

                    $objWorkSheet=$objPHPExcel->createSheet(1);

                    // Add some data to the second sheet, resembling some different data types
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
                    // Rename 2nd sheet
                    //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','bbbbbbb ');
                    $objPHPExcel= $objReader->load('./report_html/report2.html');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('sheet2');

                    //$objWorkSheet->setTitle('Second sheet');

                    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="report.xls"');
                    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

                    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
                    $objWriter->save('php://output');

                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `load()` method is designed to load an entire file into a new PHPExcel object, not to load new sheets into an existing PHPExcel object, so when you call it a second time, you're ***replacing*** what you already had from the first load, not adding to it.

My recommended option would be to load the second file into a second PHPExcel object, and then use the `addExternalSheet()` method to transfer the worksheet to your first PHPExcel object, which will add it as a second worksheet..... this mechanism is specifically written to ensure that there are no clashes in the styles, and that the new sheet retains all its existing styling.

An alternative is to use the Reader's `loadIntoExisting()` method, and as you're loading HTML documents, then this shouldn't result in any style clashes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have updated code for sheet2 by using addExternalSheet
<?php 
$objPHPExcel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $objPHPExcel2= $objReader->load('./report_html/report2.html');
 $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel2->createSheet(0);
  
 $objPHPExcel->addExternalSheet($objWorkSheet);
  
 $objWorkSheet->setTitle('Second sheet');
   ?>
It creates sheet but doesn't append data to it  
Please guide

Comment: `$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel2->createSheet(0);` creates a new empty sheet in `$objPHPExcel2`, and you then try to add that new empty sheet to `$objPHPExcel`..... why are you creating a new empty sheet? I thought you wanted to copy the existing sheet

Comment: Thanks !! I got wht you want to say ..Gr8 help !!  Have updated code like this
`code` $objPHPExcel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $objPHPExcel2= $objReader->load('./report_html/report_3CB_24.html');
 $objWorkSheet=$objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('sheet2');
 
 $objPHPExcel->addExternalSheet($objWorkSheet);

This has attached second sheet with html.  But now facing some garbage printed in excel from html  Can you please help with that also ..

Comment: As I have no idea what your files are like, or what the resulting file should contain, or what it looks like when you've done this, it's almost impossible for me to say.... besides the fact that `$objPHPExcel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);` should trigger an error as you're calling it before `$objPHPExcel2` exists

Comment: Hi @Mark , 
I have created multiple sheets from html. But one more question can we directly write in sheet by using variable , means instead reading html and then writing in excel , can we directly write php variable content in excel sheet.  This will help to get some of basic formatings in html in excel. please give an example

Comment: Perhaps you should try reading the PHPExcel documentation and looking at the examples, there's a lot of information there about how to write values into Excel worksheets

Comment: I have found few examples which writes in excel cells , But my requirement is to write string which is having html tags with some formattings. Content is written in sheets but it does not take the styles or width applied to table columns. So need a way to append string to worksheet. can you please help? @Mark

Comment: You cannot automagically create a native Excel format spreadsheet from html; the two are completely different. You need to do some work to convert from one to the other, and while PHPExcel provides some helper functions for parsing HTML into rich text cell objects, there's no magic that will simply let you "append" markup to an Excel file